# R - Speeding up a search with apply

Tags: r, performance, data.table, apply

Suppose I have a `data.table` in which an observation is a pair-wise combination of products my consumers buy together.

I would like to find, for each pair of products (a row in `dt`) in my `data.table`, if they have a third product in common that is sometimes also bought with one of the products.

I want to include the "common products" as a new column in `dt`.

Currently, I do this as follows. But my real data holds millions of rows. It takes 20 hours to compute data from 1 week.

How can I speed this up? Is an `apply` function smart, or should I think about mapping?

Mock example:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
library(future.apply)

set.seed(1)

# build mock data
dt <- data.table(V1 = stri_rand_strings(100, 1),
                 V2 = stri_rand_strings(100, 1))

head(dt,17)
#   V1 V2
#1:  G  e
#2:  N  L
#3:  Z  G
#4:  u  z
#5:  C  d
#6:  t  D
# 7:  w  8
# 8:  e  T
# 9:  d  v
#10:  3  b
#11:  C  y
#12:  A  j
#13:  g  M
#14:  N  Q
#15:  l  9
#16:  U  0
#17:  i  i

#function to find common products
find_products <- function(a, b){
  library(data.table)
  toString(unique((dt[.(c(a, b)), on=.(V1), V2[duplicated(V2)]])))
}

#initiate parallel processing
plan(multisession) # on Windows machine - use plan(multicore) on Linux

#apply function across rows
common_products <- future_apply(dt, 1, function(y) find_products(y['V1'], y['V2']))

dt_final <- cbind(dt, common_products)

#head(dt, 17)
#    V1 V2 common_products
# 1:  G  e                
# 2:  N  L                
# 3:  Z  G                
# 4:  u  z                
# 5:  C  d                
# 6:  t  D                
# 7:  w  8                
# 8:  e  T                
# 9:  d  v                
#10:  3  b                
#11:  C  y                
#12:  A  j                
#13:  g  M                
#14:  N  Q                
#15:  l  9                
#16:  U  0                
#17:  i  i      i, z, B, l
```

Comment: You load the data.table library in every row. This is slow. Pair (a,b) should give the same results as pair (b,a). This can cut your analysis time in half. By using parallelization on each row, you are losing the benefits on vectorization and adding an overhead in copying the data to the parallel workers.

Comment: Why doesn't `dt` contain a third column? Do we have one purchase per row e.g the first customer bought products G and e?

Comment: So you want to to add third logical column to your table?

Comment: @danlooo Interesting. Is there a way to vectorize this? For this use-case we are interested in pair-wise product purchases. Hence this set-up of two products per row. The desired output is now listed below.

Comment: @sindri_baldur Sorry, I've now added the desired output. It is a new column with the common products.

Comment: If pair (a,b) is equivalent to pair (b,a), then you should have additional combinations, e.g. using your example, the triplet "6", ¨d" and "B" (check `dt_final[V1 %in% c("6", "d", "B") & V2 %in% c("6", "d", "B")]`)

Comment: How many unique products are in the database?

Comment: @jblood94 - about 166000 products.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the desired output. Why not also list 5, 7, and E in row #17 since those values appear in V1 when V2 = "i"?

Comment: If row 1 has G and e, and row 8 has e and T, why isn't T a common product in row 1?

Comment: T is only a common product if also G is bought together with T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can think of the three-way pairs as triangles in an undirected graph. The package `igraph` can find these efficiently. I included an example with 20M pairs of 3-character product codes. It ran on a single thread in about 70 seconds.

```r
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
library(igraph)

getpaired <- function(g, id) names(unique(neighbors(g, id)))
commonProducts <- function(dt) {
  blnSort <- dt$V1 > dt$V2
  dt[blnSort, c("V2", "V1") := list(V1, V2)] # sort each row
  # get triangles
  g <- graph_from_data_frame(dt, FALSE)
  m <- matrix(V(g)$name[triangles(g)], ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
  # sort each row
  m <- matrix(m[order(row(m), m, method = "radix")], ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
  dt3 <- as.data.table(m)
  # map common products back to the original dataframe
  dt3 <- rbindlist(
    list(
      # the three ordered pairs in each triangle
      dt3,
      dt3[, c(1, 3, 2)],
      dt3[, c(2, 3, 1)],
      # common products in "two-sided" triangles
      dt[V1 == V2][
        , .(V2 = V2, V3 = .(getpaired(g, V1))), by = "V1"
      ][
        , .(V1 = rep(rep.int(V1, lengths(V3)), 2),
            V2 = c(rep.int(V1, lengths(V3)), unlist(V3)),
            V3 = c(unlist(V3), rep.int(V1, lengths(V3))))
      ][ # sort (V1, V2) in each row
        V1 > V2, c("V2", "V1") := list(V1, V2)
      ]
    ),
    FALSE # bind by index
  )[ # collapse common products into a single vector for each pair
    , .(V3 = .(V3)),
    by = c("V1", "V2")
  ][ # join into the original (row-sorted) data.table
    dt, on = c("V1", "V2")
  ][ # unsort V1, V2 in each row to match the original (unsorted) data.table
    , c("V1", "V2") := dt[blnSort, c("V2", "V1") := list(V1, V2)]
  ]
}

set.seed(1)

# build mock data
dt <- data.table(V1 = stri_rand_strings(100, 1),
                 V2 = stri_rand_strings(100, 1))

dt3 <- commonProducts(dt)
print(dt3)
#>      V1 V2              V3
#>   1:  G  e                
#>   2:  N  L                
#>   3:  Z  G                
#>   4:  u  z                
#>   5:  C  d               B
#>   6:  t  D               t
#>   7:  w  8                
#>   8:  e  T                
#>   9:  d  v                
#>  10:  3  b                
#>  11:  C  y                
#>  12:  A  j                
#>  13:  g  M                
#>  14:  N  Q                
#>  15:  l  9                
#>  16:  U  0                
#>  17:  i  i i,7,E,B,5,z,...
#>  18:  z  6                
#>  19:  N  R               S
#>  20:  m  d                
#>  21:  v  z                
#>  22:  D  U                
#>  23:  e  U                
#>  24:  7  A                
#>  25:  G  k                
#>  26:  N  S               R
#>  27:  0  V                
#>  28:  N  C                
#>  29:  r  E                
#>  30:  L  a                
#>  31:  T  Z                
#>  32:  b  4                
#>  33:  U  2                
#>  34:  B  d             C,6
#>  35:  p  v                
#>  36:  f  b                
#>  37:  n  Y                
#>  38:  6  W               j
#>  39:  i  z               i
#>  40:  P  V                
#>  41:  o  g                
#>  42:  e  b                
#>  43:  m  E                
#>  44:  Y  G                
#>  45:  W  j                
#>  46:  m  S                
#>  47:  1  A                
#>  48:  T  k                
#>  49:  j  6               W
#>  50:  g  r                
#>  51:  T  c                
#>  52:  r  Y                
#>  53:  R  K                
#>  54:  F  S                
#>  55:  4  V                
#>  56:  6  B               d
#>  57:  J  W                
#>  58:  W  4                
#>  59:  f  H                
#>  60:  P  D                
#>  61:  u  H                
#>  62:  I  t               t
#>  63:  S  R               N
#>  64:  K  m                
#>  65:  e  s                
#>  66:  F  P                
#>  67:  T  3                
#>  68:  l  K                
#>  69:  5  i               i
#>  70:  s  K               O
#>  71:  L  d                
#>  72:  q  q           P,q,q
#>  73:  L  r               d
#>  74:  K  O               s
#>  75:  T  N                
#>  76:  t  t       D,I,t,x,t
#>  77:  r  d               L
#>  78:  O  j                
#>  79:  m  b                
#>  80:  x  t               t
#>  81:  Q  I                
#>  82:  i  B               i
#>  83:  O  s               K
#>  84:  K  V                
#>  85:  k  s                
#>  86:  C  B               d
#>  87:  i  l               i
#>  88:  7  i               i
#>  89:  F  w                
#>  90:  8  X                
#>  91:  E  i               i
#>  92:  3  O                
#>  93:  d  6               B
#>  94:  s  v                
#>  95:  m  H                
#>  96:  n  a                
#>  97:  S  6                
#>  98:  P  q               q
#>  99:  o  J                
#> 100:  b  m                
#>      V1 V2              V3

# timing a much larger dataset
dt <- data.table(V1 = stri_rand_strings(2e7, 3),
                 V2 = stri_rand_strings(2e7, 3))

system.time(dt3 <- commonProducts(dt))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   72.75    3.05   71.88
dt3[lengths(V3) != 0L] # show only those pairs with common products
#>           V1  V2  V3
#>       1: GBW mDN lxF
#>       2: ix6 jpR 0VI
#>       3: xLG VeE aik
#>       4: A36 RzJ YYu
#>       5: zAo OYu zAo
#>      ---            
#> 1841567: qX9 xrW 7lb
#> 1841568: knO 2G6 knO
#> 1841569: rsU 5Rw ER8
#> 1841570: Bts 3L1 1bQ
#> 1841571: c0h pgd jxJ
```

This handles "2-sided triangles" created when `V1`==`V2` (as with row 17 in the OP example data). For example, if the entire dataset consisted of the pairs `(t, i)` and `(i, i)`, then `i` would be a common product for `(t, i)` (`i` is paired with both `t` and `i`), and `i, t` would be the common products for `(i, i)` (`i` and `t` are each paired with both `i` and `i`).

Comment: this approach works very well on the real data. However, when `igraph` object `g` has 70168 nodes and 18658114 ties or more, R crashes at `triangles(g)`. I am running Windows 10 with 128GB ram. Do you know whether this is a limitation of triangles()?

Comment: No. Not off the top of my head. So something like `dt <- data.table(V1 = sample(70168, 18658114, TRUE), V2 = sample(70168, 18658114, TRUE))`? I tried running that through my script with 16GB RAM and didn't come close to running out of memory.  By "ties" do you mean product pairings (`nrow(dt)`) or vertices (`gsize(g)`) or something else?

Comment: Sorry, `gsize(g)` gives the edges, not the vertices.

Comment: Ties as in product pairings - the edges in `igraph` object `g`. R keeps crashing with so many nodes and ties. I am using `igraph 1.2.5` with Microsoft Open R 4.0.2. I guess I could try using R 4.1 with newer versions of `igraph`.

Comment: That's probably a good place to start. I've got R 4.1.1 and `igraph` 1.3.0 running on Windows.

Comment: updated to R 4.1.3 and `igraph` 1.3.0, but still crashes at `triangles(g)`.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a reproducible example where it crashes at `triangles(g)`? I haven't been able to get it to crash there. The example in my answer was for 20M random pairings of 238328 product codes. I also tried 18658114 random pairings of 70618 products. It always finishes within a couple minutes.

Comment: No - unfortunately I can't produce a reproducible example. The crash happens on the real data, in which the products (V1 and V2) have 6 alphanumeric digits. Your code works really fast up until the data gets too large and crashes. Our last instance in which it worked, `g` has 70147 nodes and 9174496 ties. `triangles(g)` produces an object with 1070140080 ties and 70147 vertices. Maybe in the next instance (with more data), this objects goes beyond `.Machine$integer.max`? How can I debug / trace this on `triangles(g)`?

Comment: I see. Your graph is highly connected. `triangles` returns a vector as long as the number of triangles in the graph. It doesn't seem to be directly dependent on `.Machine$integer.max`. I moved to a system with 260GB RAM, and got `triangles` to return a vector of length 3e9 (vs. `.Machine$integer.max` ~ 2.15e9) from a fully connected tripartite graph (each of the 3 sets had 1k nodes). However, RAM usage shot up to ~34GB. Were you able to run 1070140080 ties and 70147 vertices through your original algorithm?

Comment: Thanks for checking, @jblood94. Yes, it ran with the old algorithm but took days. Can't bring that in production. Let me see if I can scale to a local machine with more RAM and Linux (instead of Windows). See what happens.

Comment: Nice. I did ran on a Linux machine (with more RAM). I guess the error with `triangles` is Windows specific? It also ran very fast. Thanks for this great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

## Update 3 (since `ego` crashes in large graph)

It seems the `ego` approach in Update 2 crashes due to the large size of netwoek, we probably could try it in a rowwise manner

```
g <- simplify(graph_from_data_frame(dt, directed = FALSE))
nms <- names(V(g))
dt[
    ,
    common := toString(nms[do.call(intersect, ego(g, 1, unlist(.(V1, V2)), mindist = 1))]),
    .(id = seq_along(V1))
]
```

---

## Upate 2 (to address the crash issue when using `igraph`)

Considering about the possible crashes caused by using `triangles` or `subgraph_isomorphisms` over large `igraph` object, we can use the following code (maybe sacrifices with some speed but should be a stable workaround)

```
g <- simplify(graph_from_data_frame(dt, directed = FALSE))
nms <- names(V(g))
transform(
    dt,
    common = Map(
        function(...) nms[intersect(...)],
        ego(g, 1, V1, mindist = 1), 
        ego(g, 1, V2, mindist = 1)
    )
)
```

---

## Update

I guess You can try `subgraph_isomorphisms` to find all triangles with all permuations and merge into `dt`

```
g <- simplify(graph_from_data_frame(dt, directed = FALSE))
dtg <- as.data.table(do.call(rbind, Map(names, subgraph_isomorphisms(make_ring(3), g))))
dtg[
    dt,
    on = .(V1 = V1, V2 = V2)
][
    ,
    .(common = toString(na.omit(V3))), .(V1, V2)
][
    V1 == V2,
    common := sapply(V1, function(x) toString(names(neighbors(g, x))))
][]
```

which should be fast and could give you

```
     V1 V2           common
  1:  G  e
  2:  N  L
  3:  Z  G
  4:  u  z
  5:  C  d                B
  6:  t  D
  7:  w  8
  8:  e  T
  9:  d  v
 10:  3  b
 11:  C  y
 12:  A  j
 13:  g  M
 14:  N  Q
 15:  l  9
 16:  U  0
 17:  i  i l, z, 7, B, 5, E
 18:  z  6
 19:  N  R                S
 20:  m  d
 21:  v  z
 22:  D  U
 23:  e  U
 24:  7  A
 25:  G  k
 26:  N  S                R
 27:  0  V
 28:  N  C
 29:  r  E
 30:  L  a
 31:  T  Z
 32:  b  4
 33:  U  2
 34:  B  d             C, 6
 35:  p  v
 36:  f  b
 37:  n  Y
 38:  6  W                j
 39:  i  z
 40:  P  V
 41:  o  g
 42:  e  b
 43:  m  E
 44:  Y  G
 45:  W  j                6
 46:  m  S
 47:  1  A
 48:  T  k
 49:  j  6                W
 50:  g  r
 51:  T  c
 52:  r  Y
 53:  R  K
 54:  F  S
 55:  4  V
 56:  6  B                d
 57:  J  W
 58:  W  4
 59:  f  H
 60:  P  D
 61:  u  H
 62:  I  t
 63:  S  R                N
 64:  K  m
 65:  e  s
 66:  F  P
 67:  T  3
 68:  l  K
 69:  5  i
 70:  s  K                O
 71:  L  d                r
 72:  q  q                P
 73:  L  r                d
 74:  K  O                s
 75:  T  N
 76:  t  t          D, I, x
 77:  r  d                L
 78:  O  j
 79:  m  b
 80:  x  t
 81:  Q  I
 82:  i  B
 83:  O  s                K
 84:  K  V
 85:  k  s
 86:  C  B                d
 87:  i  l
 88:  7  i
 89:  F  w
 90:  8  X
 91:  E  i
 92:  3  O
 93:  d  6                B
 94:  s  v
 95:  m  H
 96:  n  a
 97:  S  6
 98:  P  q
 99:  o  J
100:  b  m
     V1 V2           common
```

---

## Previous Answer

Perhaps this could help

```
library(igraph)

g <- simplify(graph_from_data_frame(dt, directed = FALSE))
dcast(
    melt(dt[, id := 1:.N], "id")[
        ,
        common := toString(names(V(g))[do.call(intersect, ego(g, nodes = value, mindist = 1))]),
        id
    ],
    id + common ~ variable
)[, .(V1, V2, common)]
```

which gives

```
     V1 V2           common
  1:  G  e
  2:  N  L
  3:  Z  G
  4:  u  z
  5:  C  d                B
  6:  t  D
  7:  w  8
  8:  e  T
  9:  d  v
 10:  3  b
 11:  C  y
 12:  A  j
 13:  g  M
 14:  N  Q
 15:  l  9
 16:  U  0
 17:  i  i l, z, 7, B, 5, E
 18:  z  6
 19:  N  R                S
 20:  m  d
 21:  v  z
 22:  D  U
 23:  e  U
 24:  7  A
 25:  G  k
 26:  N  S                R
 27:  0  V
 28:  N  C
 29:  r  E
 30:  L  a
 31:  T  Z
 32:  b  4
 33:  U  2
 34:  B  d             C, 6
 35:  p  v
 36:  f  b
 37:  n  Y
 38:  6  W                j
 39:  i  z
 40:  P  V
 41:  o  g
 42:  e  b
 43:  m  E
 44:  Y  G
 45:  W  j                6
 46:  m  S
 47:  1  A
 48:  T  k
 49:  j  6                W
 50:  g  r
 51:  T  c
 52:  r  Y
 53:  R  K
 54:  F  S
 55:  4  V
 56:  6  B                d
 57:  J  W
 58:  W  4
 59:  f  H
 60:  P  D
 61:  u  H
 62:  I  t
 63:  S  R                N
 64:  K  m
 65:  e  s
 66:  F  P
 67:  T  3
 68:  l  K
 69:  5  i
 70:  s  K                O
 71:  L  d                r
 72:  q  q                P
 73:  L  r                d
 74:  K  O                s
 75:  T  N
 76:  t  t          D, I, x
 77:  r  d                L
 78:  O  j
 79:  m  b
 80:  x  t
 81:  Q  I
 82:  i  B
 83:  O  s                K
 84:  K  V
 85:  k  s
 86:  C  B                d
 87:  i  l
 88:  7  i
 89:  F  w
 90:  8  X
 91:  E  i
 92:  3  O
 93:  d  6                B
 94:  s  v
 95:  m  H
 96:  n  a
 97:  S  6
 98:  P  q
 99:  o  J
100:  b  m
     V1 V2           common
```

Comment: @ThomansIsCoding - I've tried to run this on the real data again, but R crashes creating `dtg`. Once our real data produces an `igraph` object of 498.8 MB with 70168 nodes and 9329057 links or more, the crash occurs. Are there limits to igraph objects? (This occurred under Microsoft Open R 4.0.1 and R 4.1.3 using `igraph 1.3.0` on Windows 10)

Comment: @wake_wake Yes, there is a limit and your `igraph` object shouldn't be too big.

Comment: weird. I can't debug where it is failing, because R crashes with `subgraph_isomorphisms()` when G gets large. It works with subsets of the data/network. Any thoughts?

Comment: @wake_wake I think it's just because `G` is too big such that the result of `subgraph_isomorphisms()` overflowed.

Comment: I see. Is that the same issue I have with `triangles(g)` in the answer from @jblood94 below? If so, can I feed `dt` stepwise to `subgraph_isomorphisms`? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @wake_wake Yes, I think they are the same issue. If `triangles` crashed, and it woulde definitely happen to `subgraph_isomorphisms` as well since the latter yields a 6x larger dataset (all permutations of 3 elements = 6). You can see my update2 solution (maybe the speed is not as fast as your want but should be a stable one)

Comment: interesting approach. I ran the code on the real world data - but run out of memory (128GB ram). Is this associated with the map function?

Comment: @wake_wake I suspect it happens at `ego(....)` if you have a large network. Probably you can try the line `ego(...)` only to see if there is the out of memory issue, otherwise, it might be caused by `Map`.

Comment: Yup, it crashes at `ego(G, 1, dt$V1, mindist = 1)`. Are there work-arounds?

Comment: @wake_wake In your case with large graph, there might be two options to solve the issue: 1) give up using `igraph` for your problem, or 2) use `ego(...)` in a rowwise manner to your dataframe `dt`

Comment: Neat! I would be interested in both. Whichever is faster :-)

Comment: @wake_wake I added on rowwise use of `ego`, and you can check if that works for you (hope it will not crash but the speed might be not that fast)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can stick with data.table to accomplish what you want to do. As a commenter already pointed out though, you'll need to decide whether product pairings [a,b] are equivalent to [b,a] (in your example answer it is only for pairings [a,b]). Anyway, the bottleneck on this answer is the `Map()` call; you may be able to eek some more speed out of it with `future_Map()` but you'll have to test on your actual data to see if it is needed.

Also I want to flag that I kept the common products column as a list-column although you may want it in a different format. Right now it is a mix of NULL's / empty character columns when there is not a match so you may want to clean that up if you keep it as a list-column--up to you.

**Solution**:

```
dt_unique = unique(dt[, .(V1, V2)])
dt_pairs = dt_unique[, list(ref_list = list(unique(V2))), .(product = V1)]

dt_unique = dt_pairs[dt_unique, on = c("product" = "V2")]
setnames(dt_unique, c("V2", "V2_ref", "V1"))
dt_unique = dt_pairs[dt_unique, on = c("product" = "V1")]
setnames(dt_unique, c("V1", "V1_ref", "V2", "V2_ref"))

dt_unique[, common_prods := Map(function(x, y) unique.default(y[chmatch(x, y, 0L)]), V1_ref, V2_ref)]

dt_unique[, c("V1_ref", "V2_ref") := NULL]
dt_unique[dt, on = c("V1", "V2")]

     V1 V2 common_prods correct_common_prods
  1:  G  e                                  
  2:  N  L                                  
  3:  Z  G                                  
  4:  u  z                                  
  5:  C  d                                  
  6:  t  D                                  
  7:  w  8                                  
  8:  e  T                                  
  9:  d  v                                  
 10:  3  b                                  
 11:  C  y                                  
 12:  A  j                                  
 13:  g  M                                  
 14:  N  Q                                  
 15:  l  9                                  
 16:  U  0                                  
 17:  i  i      i,z,B,l           i, z, B, l
 18:  z  6                                  
 19:  N  R                                  
 20:  m  d                                  
 21:  v  z                                  
 22:  D  U                                  
 23:  e  U                                  
 24:  7  A                                  
 25:  G  k                                  
 26:  N  S            R                    R
 27:  0  V                                  
 28:  N  C                                  
 29:  r  E                                  
 30:  L  a                                  
 31:  T  Z                                  
 32:  b  4                                  
 33:  U  2                                  
 34:  B  d                                  
 35:  p  v                                  
 36:  f  b                                  
 37:  n  Y                                  
 38:  6  W                                  
 39:  i  z                                  
 40:  P  V                                  
 41:  o  g                                  
 42:  e  b                                  
 43:  m  E                                  
 44:  Y  G                                  
 45:  W  j                                  
 46:  m  S                                  
 47:  1  A                                  
 48:  T  k                                  
 49:  j  6                                  
 50:  g  r                                  
 51:  T  c                                  
 52:  r  Y                                  
 53:  R  K                                  
 54:  F  S                                  
 55:  4  V                                  
 56:  6  B                                  
 57:  J  W                                  
 58:  W  4                                  
 59:  f  H                                  
 60:  P  D                                  
 61:  u  H                                  
 62:  I  t            t                    t
 63:  S  R                                  
 64:  K  m                                  
 65:  e  s                                  
 66:  F  P                                  
 67:  T  3                                  
 68:  l  K                                  
 69:  5  i            i                    i
 70:  s  K                                  
 71:  L  d                                  
 72:  q  q            q                    q
 73:  L  r            d                    d
 74:  K  O                                  
 75:  T  N                                  
 76:  t  t          D,t                 D, t
 77:  r  d                                  
 78:  O  j                                  
 79:  m  b                                  
 80:  x  t            t                    t
 81:  Q  I                                  
 82:  i  B                                  
 83:  O  s                                  
 84:  K  V                                  
 85:  k  s                                  
 86:  C  B            d                    d
 87:  i  l                                  
 88:  7  i            i                    i
 89:  F  w                                  
 90:  8  X                                  
 91:  E  i            i                    i
 92:  3  O                                  
 93:  d  6                                  
 94:  s  v                                  
 95:  m  H                                  
 96:  n  a                                  
 97:  S  6                                  
 98:  P  q            q                    q
 99:  o  J                                  
100:  b  m                                  
     V1 V2 common_prods correct_common_prods
```

**Reproducible code** (with comments):

```
library(data.table)

n = 1e2
set.seed(1)

dt <- data.table(V1 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n, 1),
                 V2 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n, 1))

#Matching your output:
find_products <- function(a, b){
  library(data.table)
  toString(unique((dt[.(c(a, b)), on=.(V1), V2[duplicated(V2)]])))
}
dt[, correct_common_prods := apply(dt, 1, function(y) find_products(y[['V1']], y[['V2']]))]


# If (a, b) and (b, a) are equivalent, you'll want this instead:
# dt_unique = unique(rbindlist(list(dt[, .(V1, V2)], dt[, .(V2, V1)]), use.names = FALSE))
dt_unique = unique(dt[, .(V1, V2)])

# Creating list-column w/ corresponding products
dt_pairs = dt_unique[, list(ref_list = list(unique(V2))), .(product = V1)]

# Merging and re-naming. There may be a more data.table way to 
# handle the renaming because this feels not-eloquent
dt_unique = dt_pairs[dt_unique, on = c("product" = "V2")]
setnames(dt_unique, c("V2", "V2_ref", "V1"))
dt_unique = dt_pairs[dt_unique, on = c("product" = "V1")]
setnames(dt_unique, c("V1", "V1_ref", "V2", "V2_ref"))

# This is the memory-intensive part because it checks for the intersection on
# each row. This creates a list-column `common_prods`
# OR, easier to read but slower: 
# dt_unique[, common_prods := Map(intersect, V1_ref, V2_ref)]
dt_unique[, common_prods := Map(function(x, y) unique.default(y[chmatch(x, y, 0L)]), V1_ref, V2_ref)]

# Column cleanup (retain _ref columns to better understand how this works)
# then merging in the common products
dt_unique[, c("V1_ref", "V2_ref") := NULL]
dt = dt_unique[dt, on = c("V1", "V2")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem lookes like a **market basket analysis**, so I'd suggest to approach it as such.

Probelm with ramdom sample data, is that you will most likely not find any strong correlations between products since your data is ramdom ;-).
But perhaps (hopefully) this will not be the case in your production-dataset(s).

There is a great tutorial on basket analysis on datacamp, which I followed (mostly) for this answer. For more in-depth information, make sure to follow the tutorial yourself. Link is in de code's comments below.

```
# Workflow adapted from 
#   https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/market-basket-analysis-r
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(tidyverse)

# Put items bought together intoa single column, separate with comma
#  then convert into transactions
write.csv(setDF(dt) %>% unite("items", everything(), sep = ","),
          "./temp/my_transactions.csv", 
          quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
# Now read the csv into a transactions file
tr <- read.transactions("./temp/my_transactions.csv", 
                        format = "basket", sep = ",")

# Frequency plot (for getting insight only, so commented out)
#   itemFrequencyPlot(tr, topN = 15, type = "absolute", main="Absolute Item Frequency Plot")
#   itemFrequencyPlot(tr, topN = 15, type = "relative", main="Absolute Item Frequency Plot")

# Mine rules
# since your sample data is rather small and ramdom.. 
# there will not be many items bought together frequently...
# so I set the confidence to 0.5 (i.e. 50%).
# If your data set grows, you should/can increase the confidence 
# to get more reliable pairing
association.rules <- apriori(tr, parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.5, maxlen = 100))

# what have we found here?
inspect(association.rules)
#      lhs    rhs support    confidence coverage   lift      count
# [1]  {x} => {t} 0.00990099 1.0        0.00990099 25.250000 1    
# [2]  {5} => {i} 0.00990099 1.0        0.00990099 14.428571 1    
# [3]  {c} => {T} 0.00990099 1.0        0.00990099 16.833333 1    
# [4]  {1} => {A} 0.00990099 1.0        0.00990099 33.666667 1    
# [5]  {p} => {v} 0.00990099 1.0        0.00990099 25.250000 1    
# [6]  {2} => {U} 0.00990099 1.0        0.00990099 25.250000 1    
# [7]  {9} => {l} 0.00990099 1.0        0.00990099 33.666667 1    
# [8]  {M} => {g} 0.00990099 1.0        0.00990099 33.666667 1    
# [9]  {y} => {C} 0.00990099 1.0        0.00990099 25.250000 1    
# [10] {X} => {8} 0.00990099 1.0        0.00990099 50.500000 1    
# [11] {8} => {X} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 50.500000 1    
# [12] {q} => {P} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 12.625000 1    
# [13] {a} => {n} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 25.250000 1    
# [14] {n} => {a} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 25.250000 1    
# [15] {a} => {L} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 12.625000 1    
# [16] {0} => {U} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 12.625000 1    
# [17] {0} => {V} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 12.625000 1    
# [18] {u} => {H} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 16.833333 1    
# [19] {u} => {z} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 12.625000 1    
# [20] {Q} => {I} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 25.250000 1    
# [21] {I} => {Q} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 25.250000 1    
# [22] {Q} => {N} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198  8.416667 1    
# [23] {Z} => {G} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 12.625000 1    
# [24] {Z} => {T} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198  8.416667 1    
# [25] {f} => {H} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 16.833333 1    
# [26] {f} => {b} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198  8.416667 1    
# [27] {n} => {Y} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 16.833333 1    
# [28] {o} => {J} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 25.250000 1    
# [29] {J} => {o} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 25.250000 1    
# [30] {o} => {g} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 16.833333 1    
# [31] {J} => {W} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 12.625000 1    
# [32] {I} => {t} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 12.625000 1    
# [33] {w} => {8} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 25.250000 1    
# [34] {8} => {w} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 25.250000 1    
# [35] {w} => {F} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 16.833333 1    
# [36] {7} => {A} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198 16.833333 1    
# [37] {7} => {i} 0.00990099 0.5        0.01980198  7.214286 1 

# what does the above mean?
#    [1] 100% of people that have bought x, also bought t
#   [11]  50% of people that have bought 8, also bought X

# visualise
plot(association.rules, method = "graph",  engine = "htmlwidget")

plot(association.rules, method="paracoord")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is an interesting perspective. How fast is this? Scalable to millions of records?

Comment: it should work... but make sure to start with a pretty restrictive `parameter = list(...))` in  the `apriori` line of code... You do not want (nor need) thousands of possible relations.
Make sure to read a tutorial (or two, or three) so you can interpretate the results. [This one](https://scienceofdata.org/2019/10/27/market-basket-analysis-the-apriori-algorithm/) has a bit more thoretical background.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, for the real-world example we are interested in all common products (our objectives are somewhat different from market basket analysis). So for this to work in our case, we would have to parameterize a very loose setting.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies if I'm misunderstanding the question (it does reproduce the example, fwiw), but this seems like it might be doable more efficiently as a simple join. For n = 10M, this runs in about 3 seconds.

My `data.table` is rusty so I'm using `dtplyr` to convert my `dplyr` to `data.table` syntax. I presume there are `data.table` optimizations to make this faster, or you could use the `collapse` package.

Setup

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)   
library(dtplyr)    
library(stringi)
n = 10000000
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(V1 = stri_rand_strings(n, 2),  # 3,844 groups
                 V2 = stri_rand_strings(n, 2))
```

Join of V2 to each associated V1

```
dt_single <- distinct(dt, V1)
dt_single %>%
  left_join(dt, by = c("V1" = "V1")) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarize(common_products = paste(V2, sep = ", ", collapse = ", "))
```

To get the output in the same format as the OP, we could assign the code above to `-> common` and then do:

```
dt %>%
  left_join(common) %>%
  mutate(common_products = if_else(V1 == V2, common_products, "")) %>% 
  select(V1, V2, common_products)
```

to get the OP desired output, as far as I can tell:

```
   V1    V2    common_products
   <chr> <chr> <chr>          
 1 G     e                   
 2 N     L                   
 3 Z     G                   
 4 u     z                   
 5 C     d                   
 6 t     D                   
 7 w     8                   
 8 e     T                   
 9 d     v                   
10 3     b                   
11 C     y                   
12 A     j                   
13 g     M                   
14 N     Q                   
15 l     9                   
16 U     0                   
17 i     i     i, z, B, l  
...
```

Comment: thank you! Unfortunately, this doesn't reproduce the example on my machine. It does for you?

Comment: It's a different order but I think it's giving you what you need to produce the same output. Edited to show a last step that seems to produce the same results, with the common products only shown when V1 = V2.

Comment: It gets very close, but misses a couple common products. For instance, it misses common product `S` on row 19 and `R` on row 26.